# Defining PYTHONPATH automatically in virtualenvs

Tags: python, virtualenv

Is possible to configure PYTHONPATH for a virtualenv automatically with mkvirtualenv? I don't define PYTHONPATH in my ~/.bashrc, but in each virtualenv. Every time I create a new virtualenv, I have to put these lines in `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate` manually:

in deactivate function:

```
unset PYTHONPATH
```

outside deactivate:

```
PYTHONPATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
```

I'd like to put these lines automatically with mkvirtualenv. I'm using virtualenv 1.7.1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path `$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages` is default in virtualenv. I only removed [ipython](http://ipython.org/) from my system and installed it inside virtualenv:

```
workon myvirtualenv
pip install ipython
```

Thus, I checked path using inside ipython using:

```
import sys
sys.path
```